# Android NDK - Building Limbo Android returns fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, linux-mint

I'm trying to rebuild [Limbo Android](https://code.google.com/p/limbo-android/). I'm on Linux Mint.

All I changed was android-config.mak NDK_ROOT, exported variables NDK_ROOT. I've also exported NDK_MODULE_PATH to /home/pathtoandroidndk/sources, as per README instructions.

From terminal I do `cd limbo-android/jni` and then `make`.
Building returns this error:

```
jni/glib/glib/./libcharset/localcharset.c:22:20: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/glib-2.0/./libcharset/localcharset.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/me/limbo-android'
```

I've tried modifing Android.mk following instructions from [Android NDK - Additional Include Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483595/android-ndk-additional-include-directories) and [Unable to find header files - Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594836/unable-to-find-header-files-android-ndk), without success.

I came to conclusion that each module inside limbo-android needs it's own config.h file, while libcharset does not have one.

How do I solve this error? Is there a generic config.h (the one from NDK maybe?)
NOTE: I can build it without any problems on Windows 8.1 using mingw.

Comment: try using ndk-build  cd to proj root  $ ndk-root/bin/ndk-build   this should employ the 'Android.mk' in the jni folder  http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/

Comment: I already did. It's still the same error.