# "OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented" on Android app

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, opencv3.0

I am working with OpenCV (version 3.2) on an Native Android app using ndk-build.
I got an error that I cannot get around.

```
E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (Unknown/unsupported array type) in int cv::_InputArray::type(int) const, file /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1931
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00001f38 (code=-6), thread 8011 (CameraHandlerTh)
```

By using the debugger I found the code part that throws this error.
`cv::findHomography();`

```
void Homography33::compute() {
  if ( valid ) return;

  std::vector<cv::Point2f> sPts;
  std::vector<cv::Point2f> dPts;
  for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    sPts.push_back(cv::Point2f(srcPts[i].first, srcPts[i].second));
  }
  for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    dPts.push_back(cv::Point2f(dstPts[i].first - cxy.first, dstPts[i].second - cxy.second));
  }
  cv::Mat homography = cv::findHomography(sPts, dPts); // throws error
  for (int c=0; c<3; c++) {
    for (int r=0; r<3; r++) {
      H(r,c) = homography.at<double>(r,c);
    }
  }

  valid = true;
}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you get the whole stack trace? (at least the OpenCV related frames)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For futur reference.

After searching for a while...

I am using external module (namely ros indigo) that contains an older version of OpenCV. it clashes with the newer version i'm using (OpenCV 3.2).

The solution is to separate the two modules in your android.mk (or cmake).

BUT after that, for ndk-build users, include files won't be find correctly across modules... [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594836/unable-to-find-header-files-android-ndk)